# Delete Related Data in EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

Two entities with one to many relationship such that a voucher has many voucher details, the problem is when removing one item from the collection of the related data (voucher details) and then saving the changes the entity is not removed from the related table

The delete procedure looks like:

```
    var voucher = await _voucherRepository.GetCompleteVoucherAsync(Id);
    var item = voucher.VoucherDetails.FirstOrDefault();
    voucher.VoucherDetails.Remove(item);
    _dbContext.Update(voucher);    
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

And the Model looks like:

```
 public class Voucher : BaseEntity
 { 
        public int Id {get; set;}
        -----
        public ICollection<VoucherDetail> VoucherDetails { get; set; }
 }

 public class VoucherDetail : BaseEntity
 {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        -----
        public int VoucherId { get; set; }
        public Voucher Voucher { get; set; }
 }
```

and here is the context:

```
builder.HasOne(i => i.Voucher)
           .WithMany(i => i.VoucherDetails)
           .IsRequired().HasForeignKey(i => i.VoucherId)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Repository:

```
public async Task<Voucher> GetCompleteVoucherAsync(int id)
        {
            return await _dbContext.Vouchers
            .Include(i => i.VoucherSource)
            .Include(i => i.VoucherDetails)
            .ThenInclude(i => i.Assets)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
        }
```

With the above setup insert and update procedures are working perfectly for both the Voucher and/or the VoucherDetails entities only by updating the voucher entity directly.
but removing an item from the Voucher Details collection does not seem to trigger a delete statement against the Voucher details entity.

is there anything else that I'm missing?

**Edit** 
Edited to show the implementation for the GetCompleteVoucherAsync method

Comment: With the line 'var item = voucher.VoucherDetails.FirstOrDefault();', item could end up as a new VoucherDetails object.  Have you verified that item is not a new VoucherDetails object with no actual data in it?

Comment: Can you share the Code/SQL for 'GetCompleteVoucherAsync'?

Comment: @TonyAbrams Edited the question to show the GetCompleteVoucherAsync method, and regarding the item I'm sure it is an existing record from the db and not an empty/new record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are just removing the item from the VoucherDetails collection on the voucher object.  This is not the same as triggering EF to delete the item from the DBSet.

Change the following line:

```
voucher.VoucherDetails.Remove(item);
```

To this line:

```
_dbcontext.VoucherDetail.Remove(item);
```

Comment: I know that this will work, but i expected EF to handle deleting through the parent collection just as it handles the insert and update scenarios. The question is (Does EF issue a delete statement for missing items from a child/related items collection?)

Comment: In your scenario, it does not.  You would have to go into each entity and mark the state as deleted.

Comment: This is because you are not calling the remove on a DB context.  You are calling Remove on an Array/Collection/List.

Comment: I agree with @halfraed.  I would expect EF to recognize that an item from the collection is gone; just as it recognizes that a new one exists; on Update.  You shouldn't have to worry about modifying the context manually in one scenario but ignoring it in the other.  This to me is a limitation of EF.  If you've figured out a way to make this work let me know, I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: is there any solution found in latest ef core like it recognizes new child entity on update,will it track delete also

Comment: As soon as you do `SingleOrDefault` or some other operation like `ToList`, you're breaking the connection with the dbContext. If you pass around the output as an IQueryable, then what has been said by @halfraed and @Mike is accurate, but once you break the connection then the Context no longer has any reference to the objects; the link has been severed.

Comment: @ShafiqJetha - it's not generally true that the link to Context is severed by doing a `ToList()` or `SingleOrDefault()` (although clearly something is going on in the OP's case). If the object is produced by a tracking query then it's still tracked. Just look in `context.ChangeTracker.DebugView.ShortView` for details, calling `context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` first if needed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/debug-views

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this? I am about to create a single field with JSON data to manage, but I really do not want to do that.